# Error while checking for headers using :selenium web driver in rspec/capybara test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, rspec, capybara

I have a `rspec/capybara` test which fails with the following error because `Selenium` does not support headers, however this test works fine with `:rack_test` driver. Since a lot of my other tests heavily rely on `Selenium` I cannot change the driver to `:rack_test`.

How do I fix this? Is there a way to run this specific test with `:rack_test` driver while other tests still use the default `:selenium` driver?

**error-report.xml**

```
    <failure message="Capybara::Driver::Base#response_headers" type="Capybara::NotSupportedByDriverError">
      <![CDATA[Capybara::Driver::Base#response_headers
./spec/feature/transaction_search_spec.rb:35:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>']]>
    </failure>
```

**rails_helper.rb**

```
 Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = false
 Capybara.configure do |c|
   c.default_driver = :selenium     # BREAKS :(  !!!!!
   c.app_host = "http://localhost:3000"
 end
```

**transaction_search_spec.rb**

```
require 'rails_helper'
require 'capybara/rspec'

RSpec.feature 'Transaction Search' do

  scenario ' - Download CSV scenario' do
    visit '/signin'
    fill_in 'Email', :with => 'user@payments.org'
    fill_in 'Password', :with => 'Password123'
    page.find('#login').click

    expect(page).to have_content('Stores:')

    # search page
    visit '/search'
    expect(page).to have_content('Search')
    click_button 'Search'

    sleep 5

    click_button 'Download CSV'
    expect(page.response_headers['Content-Type']).to eq('text/csv; charset=utf-8; header=present')
    # expect(page.response_headers['Content-Disposition']).to match('filename="transactions.csv"')
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should be able do pass the `:driver => :rack_test` option to the `scenario` line in your test. See [this section](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#using-capybara-with-rspec) of Capybara README for a documented example.